# How to make points and lines of a higher resolution?

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a plot in R and I would like to have points and ellipse of a higher resolution. Could you maybe help me how to do that?

The code I am using is:

```
autoplot(
          pcaAroma, 
          data = keepRows,
          colour = 'Woi',
          frame.type = 'norm',
          size = 3
      )
```

[image]

Comment: How do you save the plot, and what file formats are you OK with it being in? That often makes more difference to the final appearance of a plot in R than the actual plotting code.

Comment: If you use graphic devices such as `jpeg`, `png` or `tiff` to save your plot, you can use the argument `res` to control the resolution of your saved plot. It as also worth experimenting with `type = "cairo"` for antialiasing.